# how can i get in my template a queryset which show me relate object from database

Tags: python, django, django-models

Well this is my views.py

```
def movieO(request, id):
    moviee = Movies.objects.get(id=id)


    moviee = {
    'moviee':moviee,


    }
    return render(request, 'moviesingle.html', contexto)
```

and my urls:

```
re_path(r'^movies/(?P<id>\d+)/$', movieO, name='moviesweb')
```

I want to show in this view all the objects in my database that are similar to the object sent or presented on the page through the id, for example, someone is in the view of the movie skyfall, I would like to show all the movies related to skyfall according to some keywords that will be added in my field tags.

this is my models.py

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='static', height_field=None, 
    width_field=None, max_length=100)
    fecha_de_lanzamiento = models.DateField()
    director = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    reparto = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pais = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sinopsis = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    puntuacion = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1, 
     blank=True, null=True)
    links = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
      ACCION = 'ACC'
      DRAMA = 'DRA'
      CIENCIA_FICCION = 'SC'
      SUSPENSO = 'SUS'
      TERROR = 'TER'
      CRIMEN = 'CRI'
    TAGS_CHOICES = (
    (ACCION, 'Acción'),
    (DRAMA, 'Drama'),
    (CIENCIA_FICCION, 'Ciencia Ficción'),
    (TERROR, 'Terror'),
    (SUSPENSO, 'Suspenso'),
    (CRIMEN, 'Crimen'),
)
    tags = MultiSelectField(choices=TAGS_CHOICES, blank=True)
    class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "Películas"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

and tags is the field that i wanna use to relate the different movies.

What I tried:

```
def peliculasO(request, id, *args, **kwargs):
    peliculaa = Peliculas.objects.get(id=id)
    relacionarr = Peliculas.objects.filter(Q(tags__icontains=peliculaa.tags))
    contexto = {
        'peliculaa':peliculaa,
        'relacionarr':relacionarr
        }

    return render(request, 'moviesingle.html', contexto)
```

but when i call it through my template: {{relacionarr}} i just get a empty query and there are in my database objects with the same info.

Comment: That's fine. Now you described what you're trying to do, maybe you could also explain what you did to make it happen and what problem you have ?

Comment: i don't know how to show in my template all the related objects in my database through tags field in my models, and i wanna do that

Comment: for example: i have spiderman in my database whit a tags called: marvel, in the page of spiderman i wanna show all the related movies which have marvel in their tags field, sorry for my english i'm trying to...

Comment: Ok we already understood what you wanted to do, what I'm asking for is "what have you done to make it happen and where are you stuck ?". Ok I'll give you a hint: your template's context can contain as many keys as you want, so you can add a queryset of related movies here, then display it in your templates.

Comment: i do nothing about, i have no idea how to do that, please, can you explain me in code :(, i have tried it of a bunch of ways, but i never do it correctly

Comment: i don't know how to make a queryset of related movies

Comment: So I have to ask once again: __what have you tried that didn't work ?__ You have to understand that SO is not a free code writing service, we're all willing to help but you have to show some effort.

Comment: i put an answer when i show what i have done

Comment: one issue, when the object is empty it shows me all the objects empty, but when the objects have a value, don't show anything even there are others objects with same value, so what...?

Comment: i have a theory, maybe the value (peliculaa.tags) that i give to the objects through the view is empty so for that, it just show me the objects with that value in empty, but when i change the value of the movie open in my project web page, it doesn't continue show me the movies which have the objects empty so it is getting the value tags of the movie open so, i don't understand why doesn't it show me the value relate o similar when it is not empty, does not have sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a non standard field (MultiSelectField) which stores values in a denormalized way. This sure makes querying harder than a proper design which would have used a `Tag` model and m2m field to this `Tag` model in `Peliculas`.

You didn't even posted which package you got this MultiSelectField from, but if it's this one https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield then what you want should be something like (untested of course):

```
import operator

def peliculasO(request, id, *args, **kwargs):
    peliculaa = Peliculas.objects.get(id=id)
    tags = peliculaa.get_tags_list() 
    q = reduce(operator.or_, [Q(tags__icontains=tag.lower()) for tag in tags])
    relacionarr = Peliculas.objects.filter(q)

    # etc
```

Note that this may yield false positive if you have for example "foo" and "foobar" in your tags since "foobar" 'contains' "foo".

With a proper design:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(unique=True, ...)
    # ...

class Peliculas(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToMany(Tag, related_name='peliculas')
    # ...
```

You could have just used:

```
    relacionarr = Peliculas.objects.filter(tags__in=peliculaa.tags.all())
```

Comment: You made it looks so obvius, thanks and you give me an idea to make the same with reparto = models.CharField(max_length=200) change it to: reparto = models.ManyToManyField(Cast) and have a database for the actors, thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
def peliculasO(request, id, *args, **kwargs):
    peliculaa = Peliculas.objects.get(id=id)
    relacionar = Peliculas.objects.all()
   relacionarr = Peliculas.objects.filter(Q(tags__icontains=peliculaa.tags))
    contexto = {
        'peliculaa':peliculaa,
        'relacionarr':relacionarr


        }

    return render(request, 'moviesingle.html', contexto)
```

well in this view, i'm trying to send like it was a search but already defined the info that i wanna search, i mean there is not a form which send the value but through view the value is already given, so i can get for this way the queryset that i want... but when i call it through my template: {{relacionarr}} i just get a empty query  and there are in my database objects with the same info